# Using EventToCommand at a component inside a datagrid

Tags: mvvm-light

I have a problem using MVVM Lite EventToCommand at a checkbox component inside a datagrid. EventToCommand doesn't work, the action never fires.

Not just at a checkbox component, I've try to use EventToComment at another component inside a datagrid. And It doesn't work too.

Is it possible to use EventToCommand at a component inside a datagrid? if it possible, then how to implement it?

here is the code..

xaml:

```
<sdk:DataGrid Name="dgSubmitProposal" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PeopleVM}" 
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRateChange, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      FrozenColumnCount="{Binding FrozenColumnCount}"
                      TabNavigation="Cycle"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
                      ClipboardCopyMode="None">
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Select">
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Name="chbSelect" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding RowCheckCommand}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        </sdk:DataGrid>
```

View Model Class:

```
public RelayCommand RowCheckCommand
{
    get;
    private set;
}
public MainViewModel()
{
    RowCheckCommand = new RelayCommand(() => MessageBox.Show("A checkbox in a datagrid Clicked!"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    RelayCommand = new RelayCommand(() => MessageBox.Show("A checkbox in a datagrid Clicked!"));
}
```

in this code there is an error. You're creating RelayCommand for property: **RelayCommand**. You should do it for **RowCheckCommand** property

Comment: sorry my mistake, It suppose to be "RowCheckCommand". It doesn't work